# Запрет на кэширование определённого сайта Squid

Tags: squid, proxy, freebsd, linux

Доброго дня!
Собственно squid надо заставить один из сайтов не кэшировать, добавил следующую acl в squid.conf:

```
acl NOCACHEDOMAIN dstdomain www.123.runo_cache deny NOCACHEDOMAIN
```

перезапустил squid... не помогло. Может кто уже делал, подскажите, что не так...

Comment: Посмотрите в логи Squid (cache.log), нет ли там ошибок или предупреждений?

Answer (score 2):

На первый взгляд, все Ок. Попробуйте изменить конфиг, например, так:

```
acl NOCACHEDOMAIN dstdomain www.123.rucache deny NOCACHEDOMAIN
```

или так

```
acl NOCACHEDOMAIN dstdomain www.123.rualways_direct allow NOCACHEDOMAIN
```